# How can I configure a progress bar to indicate search query progress?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, and javascript

I have a search bar. User can type in keywords and hit 'search button' (LinkedButton). On back end I am using VB asp.net to write my query and search the database. After that page refreshes and new results are display on page.

Soon as user hit LinkButton, I want the progress bar to run. progress bar is completed when page is refreshed.

issues is that this bar is not in real time. Curreclty I am increasing the progress but using width variable (static).

How can I turn this javascript 'move' function into real time progress bar?

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="AdvSearchB" runat="server">Search</asp:LinkButton>

<div id="myProgress" style="width: 100%; background-color: #ddd;">
<div id="myBar" style="  width: 0%;height:3px;" class="progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.AdvSearchBC').click(function () {
        move();
    });
});

function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
                  clearInterval(id);
              } else {
                  width++;
                  elem.style.width = width + '%';
              }
          }
}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to rephrase this as 'animate the progress bar for the duration of search process' ?

Comment: So how will the front end know how much progress has been completed?

Comment: @ProEvilz, feel free to edit for clarity. That's how SE works.

Comment: *possible* duplicate.

Comment: I'd use fetch's `body.getReader()` stream to show progress if it's a big response. Also of course, don't refresh the page

Comment: So I am just curious, how would one know if you are 78% done with a search? Are you actively writing code to get total number of possible results then reporting as you are iterating through each?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: You must use AJAX.**

Your problem is actually not solvable with the approach you are taking. You cannot do anything in the UI once you make an HTTP request that is not an XMLHTTPRequest, because it will cause render blocking on the page since it's synchronous.

You have two potential solutions:

1. Add a time gap between the time a user clicks the button and the request is made
2. Use AJAX

Number 1 won't give you the desired effect at all because if you animate your loading bar on click, and then after it's reached 100% you begin the HTTP request, your loading bar animation is complete BEFORE the request is actually made, and that defeats the whole purpose of having a loading bar.

This means you need to use AJAX.

If you want to understand more on why this won't work for you without AJAX, [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

In short, the browser stops rendering (painting) anything in the screen because it's blocked by another action, which in this case for you will be the synchronous HTTP request. So while the synchronous HTTP request is being made, no loading bar can be animated since painting is blocked by the browser.

If you want to test this out for yourself, add a button on your page that requests a page that takes a long time to load. While the native browser spinner is loading, you will not be able to click anything else on the page because the render is being blocked. That same blocking is the very reason you can't animate a loading bar in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I did not knew that I had to use ajax. this helps. I will try to use jquery ajax

Comment: No problem. But you should try to understand *why* you need to use AJAX. If you don't understand this why, let me know and I can explain further. The *why* is very crucial so you understand as opposed to just getting the right solution. :)